# jQuery slide up / down consistently

Tags: jquery, css, browser

I am trying to reuse a piece of jQuery code accordion code that I had working perfectly [site 1](http://www.oneclickrecruitment.co.uk/about-us)

Although I am having a problem getting it to work the same [site 2](http://dev.hairatporters.co.uk/hair-salon)

Is this a CSS issue or jQuery?

EDIT:

Site 1 the accordion is the big black boxes e.g "Flat Fee Recruitment", "Who Are We?", "Why Choose Us?"
Site 2 the accordion is the brown boxes e.g "Toppic that can be expanded by click"

Comment: Below about us `Flat Fee Recruitment` etc, on his page its under `Topic that can be expanded`

Comment: btw you have css issues on your page in chrome, your scrolling marquee also jolts from time to time.

Comment: Thanks, still need to browser check it. I hate the fact that chrome is turning into an annoying internet explorer with CSS issues but without the conditional statements like in IE makes it hard to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because that you are missing to add `<p>` tag inside accordion_middle `<div>` tag.

Try to wrap your text inside `<p`> tag.